# I'd like to superpose 2 div to make an overlay over some text

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

**jsfiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/h7zq8uj2/9/

I have a div that is supposed to contain only text and another one that should contain the same text but encapsulate words into span to make an overlay. In my app the first div is editable and the overlay is used to highlight words.

My issue is that both div aren't superposed. If I remove the inline-block from the wrap they are, but I need it to be aligned with the label. I could use some tweaks like a negative left value on the overlay, but I'd prefer a cleaner solution. Any idea what is causing this issue?

Apparently I can't post a jsfiddle link without code, so here is the css:

```
label {
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.wrap {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.content, .overlay {
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  min-width: 200px;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  outline: none;
  padding: 6px;
  margin: 3px 9px 0 9px;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  pointer-events: none;
  color: red;
}

span {
  display: inline-flex;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

**EDIT:** The dog in red should be superposed with the dog in black, in practice the overlay text color is transparent and the colored span are superposed with words to highlight them.

**EDIT 2:** It works as intended on Firefox, the issue appears on google chrome.

Comment: can you explain it abit better please, im confused of the goal

Comment: @CurtisNortham I made an edit at the end, I hope it's enough to clarify my goal. You can also remove the inline-block in the wrap css if you want to see what it does when it works. Also, it does work correctly on Firefox, it's an issue with chrome only (I just realized that).

Comment: If you add a `width: 100%;` to `.content, .overlay {` it works => https://jsfiddle.net/crw54qy1/ is this what you want?

Comment: Looks like the combination of splitting this up into individual spans, and absolute positioning with its shrink-to-fit width calculation, make it break differently than the other div here. If you don’t need a dynamic width, then give both the full with of their parent, that should fix it.

Comment: @caramba That's perfect, could you post this as an answer?

Comment: Thanks @FrançoisMENTEC for the points :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `width: 100%;` to `.content, .overlay {` [Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/crw54qy1/)

```css
label {
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.wrap {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  max-width: calc(100% - 32px);
}

.content, .overlay {
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  min-width: 200px;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  outline: none;
  padding: 6px;
  margin: 3px 9px 0 9px;
  width: 100%; /* only added this line */
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  pointer-events: none;
  color: red;
}

span {
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<label>Some text</label><div class="wrap">
  <div class="content">
    The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
   </div>
  <div class="overlay"><span style="background-color: rgba(0,150,136,0.26588765477209436)">The</span> <span style="background-color: rgba(0,150,136,0.05178760621941473)">quick</span> <span style="background-color: rgba(0,150,136,0.005655135822367268)">brown</span> <span style="background-color: rgba(0,150,136,0.6454548184780486)">fox</span> <span style="background-color: rgba(0,150,136,0.020416860627113752)">jumps</span>
    <span style="background-color: rgba(0,150,136,0.32688333508523415)">over</span> <span style="background-color: rgba(0,150,136,0.39459325868567396)">the</span> <span style="background-color: rgba(0,150,136,1)">lazy</span> <span style="background-color: rgba(0,150,136,0.19584999724701302)">dog</span>.
  </div>
</div>
```